# Remove disable attribute when selecting a radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am sure this has been answered before but I am not able to find what I need.  The jsfiddle below is a basic idea of what I am trying to do.  I want the user to come to the page and the text/select fields are disabled. 
If they select EITHER of the radio buttons in the 'radio' class, I want the disable attribute to be removed from all 3 fields in the 'fields' class.  I have tried different onClick events and cannot seem to get it to work but I am not that familar with javascript and jquery.
Can anyone give me an idea of how I can make this happen?

http://jsfiddle.net/q5jqqgnt/

```
<input class="radio" name="radio" type="radio">Radio 1
<input class="radio" name="radio" type="radio">Radio 2
<br>Field 1
<input class="fields" disabled="disabled" name="field1" type="text">
<br>Field 2
<input class="fields" disabled="disabled" name="field2" type="text">
<br>Field 3
<select class="fields" disabled="disabled" name="field3" type="select">
<option>Test 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Where is the javaScript you tried?

Comment: i dont have the specific code, but what i was trying was different onclick="document.getElementByID / Class ect. As I was doing that I learned I couldnt use ID for this type of thing and I could get the class name to work

Answer (score 2):

you need to remove the disabled attribute with the `.removeAttr()` function in jQuery

```
$('.radio').change(function(){
  $('.fields').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

[**JSfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/q5jqqgnt/1/)

Comment: Thanks, that works when I run yours but when I put it in my own and update the class names I cant get it to work. Here is mine with my own class names. http://jsfiddle.net/1zwf95u0/

Comment: This is what I have in the head of my html, I dont know that I am linking the jquery correct either

<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">> 
    $('.ownerorrenter').change(function(){
    $('.mainfields').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
    </script>
    </head>

Comment: The HTML in your fiddle as well as the <script>'s you posted here appear to be misformatted. Check your HTML

Comment: I fixed your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1zwf95u0/1/). Your input radio tags were improperly formatted and you also forgot to include jQuery in the left Bar. In your actual page you will need to include jQuery in your headers and wrap the JavaScript in the fiddle in the following on-load function: `$(function(){ ... Code here ... });`

Answer (score 0):

At its simplest, I'd suggest using `prop()`, rather than `removeAttr()`:

```
$('.radio').on('change', function(){
    $('.fields').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```js
$('.radio').on('change', function() {
  $('.fields').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="radio" name="radio" type="radio" />Radio 1
<input class="radio" name="radio" type="radio" />Radio 2
<br />Field 1
<input class="fields" disabled="disabled" name="field1" type="text" />
<br />Field 2
<input class="fields" disabled="disabled" name="field2" type="text" />
<br />Field 3
<select class="fields" disabled="disabled" name="field3" type="select">
  <option>Test 1</option>
</select>
```

You could, in compliant browsers, also somewhat emulate the `disabled` property's presence, and removal, with just CSS:

```css
.radio ~ input.fields {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.radio:checked ~ input.fields {
  pointer-events: auto;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<input class="radio" name="radio" type="radio" />Radio 1
<input class="radio" name="radio" type="radio" />Radio 2
<br />Field 1
<input class="fields" name="field1" type="text" />
<br />Field 2
<input class="fields" name="field2" type="text" />
<br />Field 3
<select class="fields" disabled="disabled" name="field3" type="select">
  <option>Test 1</option>
</select>
```

Unfortunately, while this works to prevent mouse-interaction (the user cannot focus the fields with via a mouse-click), they can still use the <kbd>tab</kbd> button to focus the field and enter text, and, of course, the form-elements would still be considered 'successful' (albeit with potentially empty-values), and would be submitted to the server when the form is submitted.

So, while potentially useful under some very specific circumstances, it's almost certainly not to be used for most situations.

References:

- CSS:

  - [`pointer-events`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty).
- jQuery:

  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).